# SetInterval Method Inside A Click Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know where I am going wrong with this code.

What I am looking for:

*A list of tabs on clicking on which an animation starts and on clicking it again, it stops. I intend to do it with setInterval (just for practice).*

Here's the code that I am trying to use:

```
function writeMe() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "List 1";
    var ilu = document.getElementById("ilu");
    ilu.appendChild(p);
        if (ilu.getElementsByTagName("p").length === 5) {
            ilu.innerHTML = "";
        }
}
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(i=0;i<li.length;i++) {
        li[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if (this.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
                this.style.backgroundColor = "";
                clearInterval(writeMe);
            } else {
                for(i=0;i<li.length;i++) {
                    li[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
                }
                this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                var writeMe = setInterval(writeMe, 1000);
                writeMe();
              }
        e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
```

My logic is:

*The For loop sets the clicking conditions on EACH of the li's. Now, when they are clicked, they call the setInterval function and when clicked again, they stop it.*

Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `writeMe` isn't a function when you assign the same variable name inside the event listener. It is the timer ID. Should be seeing error in browser console telling you it's not a function

Comment: Thanks. I changed the variable name writeMe to tellMe. Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jibitil). Two issues that I am facing now: `clearInterval() not working` and as I keep on clicking on the tabs, the `animation is speeding up`!

Comment: @SamC, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43953682/2545680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach:

- In the original question you had a function named `writeMe` that you were overriding in your scope when you set the interval `var writeMe = setInterval(writeMe, 1000);`. But you also mentioned in a comment that you renamed that to `tellMe` which should have resolved that conflict.
- In your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jibitil):

  - you are trying to use the index of the loop `i` as a value. You need to understand variable scopes and closures. The clicks happen long after the loop has ended and the value of `i` might always stay at `5` (in this particular case) no matter which element you click.
  - declaring multiple `writeMe` methods like `writeMe2, writeMe3...` is NOT the solution. You'd have to add another writeMe method that does the same thing as the others except with maybe 1 or 2 value changes.
  - Using `i` multiple times within the loop without declaring it as a local variable with `var`. You are shadowing the upper-scope variable into the closure scope. Although it doesn't affect your use-case (yet), it is keeping the code open to issues in the future.

Try using the following snippet.

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function writeMe(index) {
        window.console.log('List ' + (index + 1));
    }

    function getClickHandler(index, listItems) {
        return function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();

            if (intervalTimerId) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalTimerId);
            }

            if (this.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
                this.style.backgroundColor = "";
                return;
            }

            // clear bg-color for all list-items
            for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
                listItems[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
            }

            this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

            intervalTimerId = setInterval(function () {
                writeMe(index);
            }, 1000);

            writeMe(index);
        };
    }

    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li"),
        intervalTimerId = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        listItems[i].addEventListener("click", getClickHandler(i, listItems));
    }
})();
```

I have intentionally left out the actual meat of the functionality which is for you to implement according to your requirements. If you wish to see the console logs in my code don't forget to open the development tools console in the browser you are testing.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Needing to add multiple functions later is never a good proposition from coding's perspective. Yes, the "i" was returning 5. I made a change in the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jibitil). Can you please look into it? The only problem is that it is NOT forgetting the previous setInterval. So, it is running the previous click's setInterval along with the next click's setInterval, unless I first clearInterval on the previous tab, and then click on the next tab.

Comment: @SamC you did NOT update the JSBin with my example. `intervalTimerId` (or `tellMe` in your case) needs to be declared (with `var`) outside of the click handler.

Comment: Yes, forgot mentioning in the last comment. I am trying to figure out the meaning of your code. The logic, I mean. First, why are you setting intervalTimerId as null? Second, I see that you are separating the scopes so that the event callback is not bound to the value of "i" and thus, each "li" gets a separate index parameter for itself. But isn't the "let" statement in my code doing the same thing? I also tried to change the if(intervalTimerId) { clearInterval();} into my code, but it's still not working. Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Okay, inserted the intervalTimerId as null and it started working. Why are we setting it as null?

Comment: Declaring `intervalTimerId` outside the scope is important. I set it to `null` out of habit to set the initial value of a variable as `null`. `null` values are `falsy` i.e. evaluate to a `false` in a `if` condition.

Comment: The `let` does not change the fact the listener is going to get called long after the loop has ended so `i` will still be `5`. The `getClickHandler` function preserves the value of the index inside a new local scope with `index`.

Comment: Oh okay thanks so much. Saving your code for future use.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're probably looking for:

```
    // group all functions so that we can call the one 
    // corresponding to the clicked tab
    var fns = [writeMe, writeMe1, writeMe2, writeMe3];

    var tellMe = null;
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // need to use `let` here to avoid IIFE
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            clearInterval(tellMe);
            for (let j = 0; j < li.length; j++) {
                li[j].style.backgroundColor = "";
            }
            this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            tellMe = setInterval(fns[i], 1000);
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
 .web_image {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
 }
 .next_image {
  display: none;
  text-align:center;
 }
 ul {
  background-color: #a9b9c9;
  text-align:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 li {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 class="abc def ghi jkl">Header 1</h1>
 <p id="som_thng">Restatis igitur vos; Ille enim occurrentia nescio quae comminiscebatur;</p>
 <div class="web_image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /> </div>
 <div class="next_image"><img width="350px" src="http://img06.deviantart.net/1b60/i/2013/225/5/6/shiva_by_christasvengel-d6hyf9n.jpg" /> </div>
 
 <ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
 </ul>
  <div id="ilu"></div>
<script>
 (function() {
  //var writeMe1 = setInterval(writeMe1, 1000);
  //var writeMe2 = setInterval(writeMe2, 1000);
  //var writeMe3 = setInterval(writeMe3, 1000);
    function writeMe1() {
     var p = document.createElement("p");
     p.innerHTML = "List 1.";
     var ilu = document.getElementById("ilu");
     ilu.appendChild(p);
     if (ilu.getElementsByTagName("p").length === 5) {
         ilu.innerHTML = "";
     }
    }
  function writeMe2() {
     var p = document.createElement("p");
     p.innerHTML = "List 2.";
     var ilu = document.getElementById("ilu");
     ilu.appendChild(p);
     if (ilu.getElementsByTagName("p").length === 5) {
         ilu.innerHTML = "";
     }
    }
  function writeMe3() {
     var p = document.createElement("p");
     p.innerHTML = "List 3.";
     var ilu = document.getElementById("ilu");
     ilu.appendChild(p);
     if (ilu.getElementsByTagName("p").length === 5) {
         ilu.innerHTML = "";
     }
    }
  function writeMe() {
     var p = document.createElement("p");
     p.innerHTML = "List 1";
     var ilu = document.getElementById("ilu");
     ilu.appendChild(p);
     if (ilu.getElementsByTagName("p").length === 5) {
         ilu.innerHTML = "";
   }
  }
      
      
    // group all functions so that we can call the one 
    // corresponding to the clicked tab
    var fns = [writeMe, writeMe1, writeMe2, writeMe3];

    var tellMe = null;
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // need to use `let` here to avoid IIFE
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            clearInterval(tellMe);
            for (let j = 0; j < li.length; j++) {
                li[j].style.backgroundColor = "";
            }
            this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            tellMe = setInterval(fns[i], 1000);
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
      
  var div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  div[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   div[0].style.display = "none";
   div[1].style.display = "block";
   e.stopPropagation();
  });
  div[1].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   div[1].style.display = "none";
   div[0].style.display = "block";
   e.stopPropagation();
  });
 })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```